# Cancelar DoubleClick em TreeView

Tags: c#, treeview

Eu estou utilizando uma `TreeView` para controlar as permissões no meu sistema, cada operador tem um perfil que determina o seu acesso mínimo, porem é possível dar mais permissões para um operador em especial, sem ter que criar outro perfil (por exemplo: perfil estoque e perfil supervisor do estoque), mas nunca remover uma permissão dada pelo perfil.

Para isso eu, populei a `TreeView`usando um objeto que estendi a classe `TreeNode` (lista 1) ao qual adicionei a propriedade `Enabled` que indica se a propriedade `Checked` pode ser alterada. No evento `BeforeCheck` da `TreeView` (lista 2) verifico se o nó esta `Enabled = false` e cancelo o evento. Porem ao dar um clique duplo sobre o nó o mesmo tem sua propriedade `Checked` alterada, o que fere a minha restrição. Eu tentei cancelar o evento `DoubleClick` da `TreeView`, mas assinatura do método não me permite cancelar a ação.

Resumindo: Como cancelar a ação dublo clique ou evitar que a propriedade `Checked` seja alterada por ele?

Lista 1

```
public class AccessNode : TreeNode
{
    public AccessNode(string nome, string texto)
    {
        Name = nome;
        Text = texto;
        Checked = false;
    }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; } = true;

    public void Propagate ()
    {
        /*propaga a alteração no "Cheked" para cima ou para baixo na arvore dependendo do nó atual*/
        if (Checked)
            CheckedParent();
        else
            UnCheckedNodes();
    }

    private void CheckedParent()
    {
        /*marca todos os nós do qual descende o nó atual, ou seja, pai, avô, bisavô, etc.*/
        if (Parent != null)
        {
            Parent.Checked = true;
            (Parent as AccessNode).CheckedParent();
        }
    }

    private void UnCheckedNodes()
    {
        /*desmarca todos os nós decentendes do náo atual, ou seja, os filhos, os filhos dos filhos, etc.*/
        foreach (TreeNode tn in Nodes)
            tn.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Lista 2

```
    private void treeView_BeforeCheck(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        AccessNode an = e.Node as AccessNode;

        e.Cancel = !an.Enabled;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente adicionar este trecho de código na sua classe:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x203) // identified double click
        m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
    else 
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Esse código irá desativar o duplo clique.

Veja mais sobre [aqui](http://www.csharpque.com/2012/04/treeview-checkbox-double-click.html).

Comment: Nos exemplos cita a `TreeView` mas creio que sirva no `TreeNode`, pois o `TreeNode` representa os nodos da `TreeView`. E o certo seria desabilitar na `TreeView`.

Comment: A `TreeNode` não possui esse Evento porem na `TreeView` funcionou perfeitamente, é só seguir o link e usar o código mencionado por você.

Comment: Show, que bom que funciono.